# C++ allocation of (font) resources for program duration

Tags: c++, fonts, resources

I have some resources which I want to allocate in a C++ program, and I want these resources to

- be accessable for the lifetime of the program execution
- be globally accessable

I am writing a program which requires some font resources. This consists of a class which has a pointer to some `unsigned char` data representing the rgb colors of the font. This class also has some other members such as the dimensions of a font character.

I think I can solve problem 2 by creating a static (does it have to be static?) pointer. I can declare a pointer in the font class header file, and any code which requires the font should include this header, thus having global access to the pointer.

- I don't know how to prevent the pointer from being modified during program execution however. This could be a problem, because any use code would be able to do `global_font_ptr = nullptr` which would cause the program to crash later on. Even worse would be to set it to a random address resulting in undefined behaviour.

I am not sure how to solve problem 1. I need to load my font in from a file, which should be in the same location as the program executing. Since I am writing a library, I don't want to load the font by calling a function from `int main()`, before anything else is done. This would be inconvenient for an end user who has to call that function to handle the loading of the font manually.

Can I somehow create a static instance of a class and get the class constructor to load the font?

Not sure what apporach I should be taking to solve this problem. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Fonts and resources doesn't exist in C++, they are operating system or build environment specific things. What build system (IDE) are you using? What operating system are you on? Please edit your question to include the corresponding tags.

Comment: I have my own custom font files.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is not to have a global font pointer but to wrap it inside a class who has a long-running lifespan. Exposing a pointer to a resource, especially in a header file, illustrates poor resource/memory management and can lead to problems ranging from ODR violations or hacky workarounds for lazy initialization (depending on what your code actually does).

In general:

- You want the ability to switch fonts easily without affecting global state
- You don't want to pass the burden of resource management onto the user; the init, construct and destroy pattern are superseded by RAII and classes

Comment: Your 2 points seem to be a summary of what I'm aiming for. This isn't an answer however